# Facebook Login - URL Blocked - Can't add new redirect URI's

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth

I have a website that uses the Facebook Login feature successfully and it still works as we speak. But I want to use the same facebook app on another website using the same keys etc...

But for some reason, even though I have added the correct URI's into the OAuth part of the Facebook page, I still get:

> URL blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not
>   white-listed in the app's client OAuth settings. Make sure that the
>   client and web OAuth logins are on and add all your app domains as
>   valid OAuth redirect URIs.

Does anyone have any ideas on where I can start to find out why Facebook isn't accepting these new urls?

Comment: You go to your app settings and whitelist the redirect URL

Comment: I have done this, the validator even says it's a valid URI but yet I still get the error - and everything is the same as my previous website bar the URL.

You can test my site here if it helps: https://aprillegion.com/

Comment: You whitelisted `https://aprillegion.com/fbLogin.php`?

Comment: Indeed i have yes, but the same error keeps occurring. I honestly can't figure it out - especially since i have done this plenty of times before and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it seems to be working now - perhaps was a timing issue which was wierd because it updated straight away on previous sites.

Thanks again for the help though WizKid!